# Output an exact string in Blade template

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid, laravel-blade

I am trying to add replacement tags for Sendgrid, (they look like this: `<%asm_preferences_url%>`), to my Blade template that's used in HTML E-mails. However, they are getting removed, (maybe because they look like invalid HTML tags).

Is there a way to tell Laravel or Blade, “hey, output this string exactly as it is and leave it alone”? I have tried `{!! '<%asm_preferences_url%>' !!}` but it gets stripped out. With `{{ '<%asm_preferences_url%>' }}` the < and > get turned into HTML entities, which are not recognized by Sendgrid.

#### Things I've tried:

```
<p>{!! '<%asm_preferences_url%>' !!}</p>  // becomes <p></p>
<p>{{ '<%asm_preferences_url%>' }}</p>    // becomes <p>&lt;%asm_preferences_url%&gt;</p>  
<p><%asm_preferences_url%></p>            // becomes <p></p>
```

#### Desired output:

```
<p><%asm_preferences_url%></p>
```

When I look at the compiled blade template it contains this, (when using the first method under "Things I've tried" above):

```
<?php echo '<%asm_preferences_url%>'; ?>
```

Which seems correct, so the string must be removed after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent your tags from being broken by the echo:

```
<?php echo htmlentities(<%asm_preferences_url%>); ?>
```

Comment: I don't want the <> symbols to be converted. This outputs `&lt;%asm_preferences_url%&gt;`, but I'm looking for a literal `<%asm_preferences_url%>` to be printed so it can be dealt with by Sendgrid.

Comment: Have you ever try it yet? @JohnB

Comment: Yes. The output in my comment above is from using the code you posted.

Comment: I tried it already and I get this syntax exactly `<%asm_preferences_url%>` @JohnB

Comment: Is that what you see in the browser, or what is in the HTML source? I want the HTML source to have `<%asm_preferences_url%>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182371/discussion-between-john-b-and-christian-gallarmin).